# json_decode returns NULL for a string variable

Tags: php, json

I met a really weird problem on json_decode, with this code:

```
$url="http://localhost:8983/solr/db/select?wt=json&rows=1&q=94305";
$string=file_get_contents($url);
echo $string; echo '<br><br>';
$json=json_decode($string);
var_dump($json);
```

I got the following result:

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":0,"params":{"q":"94305","wt":"json","rows":"1"}},"response":{"numFound":165,"start":0,"docs":[{"price":"","tags":"ATMs","phone_n":"","location":"37.42409897,-122.1709976 ","store":"Discover ATM","store_id":"478602","state":"CA","latitude":"37.42409897","address":"459 LAGUNITA","zipcode_n":"94305","longitude":"-122.1709976\r","url":"Discover_ATM_459_LAGUNITA_Stanford_CA_94305","city":"Stanford","category":"ATMs","text":["","CA","459 LAGUNITA","94305","Stanford"],"spell":["Discover ATM"]}]}}

NULL
```

It seems that I cannot json_decode this string. However, when I do like this (copy the output of the string above and put it to $string directly):

```
$string='{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":0,"params":{"q":"94305","wt":"json","rows":"1"}},"response":{"numFound":165,"start":0,"docs":[{"price":"","tags":"ATMs","phone_n":"","location":"37.42409897,-122.1709976 ","store":"Discover ATM","store_id":"478602","state":"CA","latitude":"37.42409897","address":"459 LAGUNITA","zipcode_n":"94305","longitude":"-122.1709976\r","url":"Discover_ATM_459_LAGUNITA_Stanford_CA_94305","city":"Stanford","category":"ATMs","text":["","CA","459 LAGUNITA","94305","Stanford"],"spell":["Discover ATM"]}]}}';
$json=json_decode($string);
var_dump($json);
```

json_decode works. Why json_decode get NULL at the first part while works properly here?

Comment: Check for BOM (Byte order mark) in the string

Comment: Perhaps the response contains a newline at the end?

Comment: Try `print_r($string)` instead of `echo $string`

Comment: First check if error occurred in parsing the json data with the code i posted in the answer. Where is the data coming from exactly?

Comment: I already checked the BOM before I post this. print_r prints the exact same thing with echo.

Comment: Don't just echo, post the output of `echo bin2hex($string)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks okay, so let's take one step closer and investigate what `$output` really is. It helps to choose a representation that can handle ASCII ranges that you can't see.

```
echo bin2hex($output);
```

That will give a huge string, but you'll be mostly interested in the front and back of the string.

If that seems kosher, you can create an in-between representation:

```
echo preg_replace('@[\x00-\x1f\x7f-\xff]@e', '" (0x" . dechex(ord("\\0")) . ") "', $output);
```

It replaces any character in the lower or higher ASCII range with a hexadecimal representation, making it somewhat easier to spot them :)

**Update**

From your investigation based on the above, your string seems to contain a carriage return - `\r` - somewhere in the middle.

```
"CA","latitude":"37.42409897","
                            ^
```

You can remove those with a `preg_replace()` if it can't be solved in another way.

```
preg_replace("/\r(?!\n)/", '', $output);
```

That removes any `\r` not followed by a `\n`.

Comment: There is some difference in the middle: 370d222c vs 3720222c

Comment: @user570494 Not sure why you have a carriage return in the middle there, but it might be causing issues ... I've updated my answer with a hackish solution .. it's better to know why solr gives you that result in the first place.

Comment: `preg_replace("/\r(?!\n)/", '', $output);` works! Thank you so much!

Comment: @user570494 Seriously weird! :) I would do some more thorough research on why solr would give you those results ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There may be some NULL bytes in the string

Remove it using

```
$string = trim($string, "\x0");
$json=json_decode($string);
var_dump($json);
```

Change the Content type to json on this page `http://localhost:8983/solr/db/select?wt=json&rows=1&q=94305`

```
header('Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Remove BOM (Byte Order mark)

```
if (substr($string, 0,3) == pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf)) { 
$string = substr($string, 3); 
}
```

Check if error occurred in parsing the json data

```
   $json_errors = array(
         JSON_ERROR_NONE => 'No error has occurred',
         JSON_ERROR_DEPTH => 'The maximum stack depth has been exceeded',
         JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR => 'Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded',
         JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX => 'Syntax error',
        );
        echo 'Last error : ',

 $json_errors[json_last_error()], PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Tried `$string = trim($string, "\x0");`, no luck.

Comment: I tried it on another server, it got " Last error : Syntax error "

Comment: The content type is set as json.

Comment: No luck with removing BOM. (there is no BOM).

Comment: then the last thing you can do is by matching the bin2hex of received json string with bin2hex of actual json string , Check this [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php)

Comment: I checked bin2hex for received json and actual json. They are identical.

Comment: I'm not sure, what's the problem then. Try using CURL instead of file_get_content() and use addslashes to json string before printing it and use stripslasges to decode it .

Comment: bin2hex found the problem for me. Thank you so much for your help! I appreciate it.